# Django: Improve page load time by executing complex queries automatically over night and saving result in small lookup table

Tags: django, django-views, django-queryset, django-database

I am building a dashboard-like webapp in Django and my view takes forever to load due to a relatively large database (a single table with 60.000 rows...and growing), the complexity of the queries and quiet a lot of number crunching and data manipulation in python, according to django debug toolbar the page needs 12 seconds to load.

To speed up the page loading time I thought about the following solution:

- Build a view that is called automatically every night, completeles all the complex queries, number crunching and data manipulation and saves the results in a small lookup table in the database
- Build a second view that is returning the dashbaord but retrieves the data from the small lookup table via a very simple query and hence loads much faster

Since the queries from the first view are executed every night, the data is always up-to-date in the lookup table

My questions: Does my idea make sense, and if yes does anyone have any exerience with such an approach? How can I write a view that gets called automatically every night?

I also read about caching but with caching the first loading of the page after a database update would still take a very long time, and the data in the database gets updated on a regular basis

Comment: I would first look at why the queries take such a long time. 60000 rows is not a large table. A normal MySQL or PostgreSQL database can handle millions of rows easily. Have you indexed your tables correctly for the queries you're making?

Comment: But yes, running nightly queries is feasible and common practice. You can use a crontab to run a django management command (which does the queries) or run something more sophisticated like django-celery.

Comment: Like @dirkgroten says, optimize your queries. Specifically try prefetch_related/select_related at least, and then try indexing your lookup columns. 60k is not a large table.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is common practice.

We are pre-calculating some stuff and we are using `celery` to run those tasks around midnight daily. For some stuff we have special new model, but usually we add database columns to the model, that contains pre-calculated information.

This approach basically has nothing to do with views - you use them normally, just access data differently.